# sphinx read the docs edit on source with self hosted gitlab

Tags: gitlab, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

The process to add the "Edit the  Source" Button on sphinx docs pages mentioned [here](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/edit-source-links-sphinx.html) is kind of working fine on public GitLab repos.

```
html_context = {
    "display_gitlab": True, # Integrate Gitlab
    "gitlab_user": "MyUserName", # Username
    "gitlab_repo": "MyDoc", # Repo name
    "gitlab_version": "master", # Version
    "conf_py_path": "/source/", # Path in the checkout to the docs root
}
```

However, how do I get it working for self-hosted Gitlab instances?

Answer (score 0):

Use the key `gitlab_host` in your `html_context` where the value of that key is the URL to your Gitlab without the `https://` e.g.

```
html_context = {
    "display_gitlab": True, # Integrate Gitlab
    "gitlab_host": "git.mycompany.com:1234"
    "gitlab_user": "MyUserName", # Username
    "gitlab_repo": "MyDoc", # Repo name
    "gitlab_version": "master", # Version
    "conf_py_path": "/source/", # Path in the checkout to the docs root
}
```

This can be used as:

```
{% if display_gitlab %}
    <a href="https://{{ gitlab_host|default("gitlab.com") }}/
    {{ gitlab_user }}/{{ gitlab_repo }}/blob/{{ gitlab_version }}
    {{ conf_py_path }}{{ pagename }}{{ suffix }}" class="fa fa-gitlab">
    Edit on GitLab</a>
{% endif %}
```

**References:**
[The documentation](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/edit-source-links-sphinx.html#gitlab)